# Demographics report setting enabled but not capture age and gender information

Tags: php, google-analytics, reporting

I enabled settings in Google Analytics as follows

1. Enable Demographics and Interest Reports - On
2. Advertising Reporting Features - On

and added the below code to my website to capture Google Analytics

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"</script>

<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

But for some reason my report doesn't show the age & gender information. Could you please advise which step I missed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socio-demographic information is based on a part of users, so especially if you have few daily visits you have to wait until you have acquired some data in the next days.

Comment: How many days it will take to update demographics data like age and gender in Google Analytics?

Comment: It depends on your site traffic, how many sessions does it (per day, week or month)?

Comment: From where google analytics fetch age and gender data? i means we need to defined anything in site or it will fetch information from google account which is right now singing?

Comment: The second you said.

Comment: Thanks it is start capturing demographics data